# Zener diode identification - no marking codes

Tags: diodes, identification, zener

[image]

Can anyone help me identify the Zener diodes marked on the PCB as D11 and D13? It's for a GoldCut 2010A cutting plotter.

[image]

Comment: Ray White - Hi, (a) Just to confirm, are you asking about the *missing* components at locations D11 and D13? (b) Why do you believe they are *Zener* diodes? (c) Component identification questions are generally for identifying components which are present - if you are asking to identify missing components then this turns into a reverse-engineering question, which may be closed due to lack of information. As a minimum, you would probably have to reverse-engineer that part of the schematic. (d) As you are new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as Stack Exchange rules differ from typical forums.

Comment: Hi Sam, I found the original photo of the mainboard where you can see the diodes are missing.

Comment: Ray White - Thanks for adding a photo of the board. I think I see where there should be 4 diodes, bottom centre near USB type-B connector P2. || I didn't see a *clear* response to my clarification questions. I *guess* you mean: (a) Yes. (b) They are not known to be definitely Zener diodes (rather than any other diode in a MELF package).  || Although [component identification questions](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710) are intended for questions where a photo of the unknown component is provided, we'll see whether the site members want to get involved even without that.

Comment: Sorry, yes I'm sure that they're meant to be Zener diodes and I'm asking about the 2 missing diodes.

Comment: Why are you assuming they are zener diodes?  D12 & D14 look like they are set up in a bridge connection.  And D13 may be connected to D12.  Also aligning with a bridge.  Tracing it out and a better quality picture and surrounding components will help.  It would make no sense to have 4 Zener diodes in the same area without corresponding series resistors.  Trace out circuit!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've uploaded some better photos.

Answer (score 1):

The picture of the whole device explains what's going on.

The four diodes are right next to a USB port:

[image]

The red lines mark the data signals from the USB port.  They go to the diodes on the one hand and further into the circuit board on the other:

[image]

Each data line has two diodes.  One goes to V+ while the other goes to ground.  The blue lines show where the ends of the diodes are connected together.  The ground is probably connected in the middle while V+ is connected on the left.

Given that, I would expect the diodes to be clamp diodes.  They'll be low capacitance diodes (so as not to load the data signals) with a low forward voltage so as to clamp the voltage to something close to the normal voltage levels for the signals.

I'd expect them to be Schottky diodes for the low forward voltage.  There are [low capacitance Schottky diodes](https://www.vishay.com/docs/85503/bas381.pdf) available that should do the job.

The photo that shows the USB connector also shows the proper polarity for the replacement diodes.  Make sure to install the new ones the right way around - if they're backwards, they'll pretty much destroy the USB port on the device and anything you connect to it.

---

Those are protection diodes to prevent damage to the USB port on the device.  It will probably function without the diodes, though it will be  susceptible to damage from eletrostatic discharge or from abnormal voltage on the USB connector from the connected PC.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the detailed answer, that'll be it. Do you have any idea what the values for the diodes that I should use should be?